# Association with custom scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 6 app, I have two models: `Course` and `Room` with a many-to-many association.

```
Class Course < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :bookings
 has_many :rooms, through: :bookings
end

Class Room < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :bookings
 has_many :courses, through: :bookings

  scope :any_size, ->  { unscope(where: :size) }
  default_scope        { where(size: 'big') }
end

Class booking < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :course
 belongs_to :room
end
```

As you can see by default, only big `Room`s are fetched. Everything works just fine when I select a big `Room`. But, when I create a new `Course`, I want to select any `Room` regardless of the size.

Now, when I try to create a `Corse` with a `small` room I get

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Room with
>   'id'=["c79cf80a-e0a1-46d8-8849-b3451d999855"] ...

I have tried to update the association as below

```
   Class booking < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :course
     belongs_to :room, -> { any_size }
    end
```

Which correctly fetches data from the DB if I manually add it but still doesn't allow me to save a new `Corse` with a `small` room.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the [`default_scope`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-default_scope).

Assuming that we've created a small room:

```
small_room = Room.create size: 'small'
```

Now, we will create a course associated with the small room:

```
course = Course.create room_ids: [small_room.id]
```

Notice the exception:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Room with 'id'=... [WHERE "rooms"."size" = ?])

ActiveRecord will first select the given room ids and will add to the select query the condition `where rooms.size = 'big'`.

You may use explicit scopes to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

can I see your code that was used to create `a Course with a small room`?

Comment: `course = Course.new(params); course.save`. The same happens also when trying to create a `Course` from the console.

Comment: and what does the `params` look like?

Comment: `{"room_ids" => ["c79cf80a-e0a1-46d8-8849-b3451d999855"] }`
As mentioned in the question, everything works just fine when I pass/select a "big" room.

Comment: Can you try this: `booking.unscoped { course = Course.new(params); course.save }`